# "invalid use of incomplete type" with variants and CRTP

Tags: c++, c++17, crtp

I have been using the curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP) with an `std::variant` as follows:

```
#include <string>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
struct either {
    std::vector<T> arg;
};

template<typename T>
struct maybe_either: std::variant<T, either<maybe_either<T>>> {

    template<typename U>
    maybe_either(U&& v):
        std::variant<T, either<maybe_either<T>>>(std::forward<U>(v)) {
    }
};

struct var {
  std::string name;
};

int main(int, char**) {
    auto expression = maybe_either<var>(either<var>{});
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled with `g++ -c -std=c++17 show.cpp`, it produces the following error when trying to resolve the target constructor:

```
/usr/include/c++/7/variant:953:2: note: candidate: template<class _Tp, class, class, class> constexpr std::variant<_Types>::variant(_Tp&&)
  variant(_Tp&& __t)
  ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/variant:953:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/7/variant:951:6: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct std::variant<var, either<maybe_either<var> > >::__to_type_impl<18446744073709551615, false>’
         typename = enable_if_t<__exactly_once<__accepted_type<_Tp&&>>
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      && is_constructible_v<__accepted_type<_Tp&&>, _Tp&&>>>
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

[Here is the full output](https://pastebin.com/Pp0gXf5T).

My version of GCC:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
```

Why does the compilation fail?

How would you recommend writing something equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is not clear, but in fact there is a mistake at this line:

```
auto expression = maybe_either<var>(either<var>{});
```

`either<var>` is not an acceptable type for the variant, but `either<maybe_either<var>>` is.

Writing this instead, works:

```
auto expression = maybe_either<var>(either<maybe_either<var>>{});
```